# Debug transaction

Tags: go-ethereum, contract-development

I have deployed smart contract and my transactions stop to reach contract from time to time.
I see that

```
INFO [06-26|16:06:57] Submitted transaction                    fullhash=0xCCCddZZZbf02961f79d1bc404b268194b43cc449b95c9e1040b63cbb7739651f5a7 recipient=0x0547cb4b5DcB9B31d30012cc0e6aE289301111df
```

transaction has been submitted to network... but what happens after, how can I trace it?

Comment: Is this transaction happening on a test/private network?

Comment: what gas price are you using?

Comment: Seems like gas price was too low...

Answer (score 1):

1. Gas price was too low
2. There were more transactions sent before. They have stuck also because of the low gas price. I had to re-send them with the same nonce to unblock.